# Many object references of ShapeDrawable

Tags: android, android-shapedrawable

I'm trying to make three seperate bars "float" down the screen, but for some reason, only one is visible. Here is my code:

```
// initialized the bar
ShapeDrawable barShape = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
barShape.getPaint().setColor(Color.CYAN);
barShape.setIntrinsicHeight(20);
barShape.setIntrinsicWidth(mDisplayWidth);

// defines an imageview with the bar in it
mBarView1 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
mBarView1.setImageDrawable(barShape);
mBarView1.setTranslationX(0);
mBarView1.setTranslationY(0);

// Copies the bars
mBarView2 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
mBarView2.setImageDrawable(barShape);

mBarView3 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
mBarView3.setImageDrawable(barShape);

// Adds the bars to the grid
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout)).addView(mBarView1);
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout)).addView(mBarView2);
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout)).addView(mBarView3);

mBarView2.setTranslationX(0);
mBarView2.setTranslationY(50);
mBarView3.setTranslationX(0);
mBarView3.setTranslationY(150);

// updates the gates every 10 milliseconds
final Handler h = new Handler();
final int delay = 10;//milli seconds

h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        moveBars();
        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

And here is my `moveBars()` method:

```
private void moveBars() {
    mBarView1.setTranslationY(mBarView1.getY() + 1);
    mBarView2.setTranslationY(mBarView2.getY() + 10);
    mBarView3.setTranslationY(mBarView3.getY() + 100);
}
```

I'm thinking it could be because they are referring to the same `ShapeDrawable` object, but if that's true, how do I fix that?

Comment: why dont you draw your bars directly on the canvas?

Comment: create a custom view, see http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Oh, ok. And then, I would just instantiate each of the views as needed?

Comment: no, all you need to override onDraw method